# Formatting a value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to format a text which is inside a span. But, its not working.

Here is my html

```
<span class="formatAmount">00000001.00</span>
```

my jquery code

```
$('.formatAmount').find('span').each(function(i) {
    if($.isNumeric($(this).text()))
    {
        $(this).text(getFormattedAmount($(this).text()));
    }
});
```

Its not going first into this loop. What's wrong in the code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

`.formatAmount` **doesn't have children**. Don't you mean:

```
$('span.formatAmount').each(function(i) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.formatAmount').each(function(i) {
if($.isNumeric($(this).text()))
{
    $(this).text(getFormattedAmount($(this).text()));
}
});
```

Comment: You forgot the tag `span` in your code. If the class is used into a `div` (for 
example) it's working too.